# How to update label after submitting mutually exclusive check boxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on C# coding and I am having problems when clicking the submit button, and select a few different combinations of checkbox answers, they are not updating with "correct" or "incorrect" correctly. How do I adjust the code to where if ONLY Answer2 and Answer3 are checked, that only the "Correct" label will show? Even if one of the wrong answers is selected with the right ones, that'll display "incorrect".

```
if (Answer2.Checked && Answer3.Checked == true)
    {
        lblQuestionResult4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblQuestionResult4.Text = "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        if (Answer1.Checked && Answer4.Checked == true)
        {
            lblQuestionResult4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblQuestionResult4.Text = "Incorrect";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach.  In your code snippet there are unaccounted for conditions.  This code avoids that by assuming the worst, and only setting the values for the correct case if it occurs (i.e. Answers 2 & 3 are checked, and all the rest are unchecked).

```
var color = System.Drawing.Color.Red; //assume incorrect answer
var label = "Incorrect";

if (Answer2.Checked && Answer3.Checked && !Answer1.Checked && !Answer4.Checked)
{
  //only the 2 correct answers have been checked
  color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
  label = "Correct";
}

// set the controls
lblQuestionResult4.ForeColor = color;
lblQuestionResult4.Text = label;
```